# find a job vs find employment

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is it natural to write "find an employment" instead of "find a job"

**Students who finish university having studied an area of science are far more likely *to find employment.***

Comment: Not "find _an_ employment", but "find employment" - "employment" is not a countable noun; you cannot use a definite (or indefinite) article with it. Using "find employment" rather than "find a job" is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Find employment" and "find a job" are both natural ways of expressing it. Note that there is no "an" before employment here - you find employment in general, not a specific employment. "Find employment" is a little more formal - a newspaper article would say "Students who finish university having studied an area of science are far more likely to find employment" whereas you'd be more likely to tell your friends "I can't find a job."

Comment: Although they are interchangeable, "employment" is often used for a career move, such as the graduate you mention.

Comment: I think you should add in the countable bit from jeff's comment